# Passing custom element to iframe

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to pass custom element to iframe,

**parent.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parent Document</title>
    <!-- Load the JavaScript file defining the custom element -->
    <script src="custom-element.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Create an iframe and load the child document -->
    <iframe src="child.html" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**custom-element.js**

```
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.textContent = "Hello from custom element!";
    }
}

customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyCustomElement);
```

**child.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Child Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Use the custom element inside the iframe -->
    <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried lot of different ways but no success, some of the options I tried,

```
window.onload = function () {
    console.log("Iframe loaded");
    const el = window.parent.customElements.get('my-custom-element');
    window.customElements.define('my-custom-element', el);
};
```

Comment: Include `<script src="custom-element.js"></script>` in `child.html` as well ...? (Or even _only_ in there, if you don't need it outside the iframe.)

Comment: @CBroe: I can't include the custom element file directly, it will have lot of dependency files also